# Не удается неявно преобразовать тип "string"

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core

Был простенький запрос на извлечение списка по убыванию из базы с пагинацией на странице:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Online(string name, int page = 1)
        {
            int pageSize = 30;   // количество элементов на странице                            

            IQueryable<Chr> source = from c in db.Chr
                                           orderby c.RCount, c.Level
                                           select new Chr()
                                           {
                                               Name = c.Name,
                                           };

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
            {
                source = source.Where(p => p.Name.Contains(name));
            }

            var count = await source.CountAsync();
            var items = await source.Skip((page - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToListAsync();

            // формируем модель представления
            IndexViewModel model = new IndexViewModel
            {
                PageViewModel = new PageViewModel(count, page, pageSize),
                FilterViewModel = new FilterViewModel(db.Chr.ToList(), name),
                Chr = items
            };

            return View(model);
        }
```

IndexViewModel:

```
public class IndexViewModel
    {
        public IEnumerable<Chr> Chr { get; set; }           
        public PageViewModel PageViewModel { get; set; }
        public FilterViewModel FilterViewModel { get; set; }       
    }
```

Недавно понадобилось взять ещё одну таблицу из базы. Что сделал я:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Online(string name, int page = 1)
        {
            int pageSize = 30;   // количество элементов на странице                            

            IQueryable<Chr> source = from c in db.Chr
                                           join g in db.GMember
                                           on c.Name equals g.Name into gg
                                           from ggg in gg.DefaultIfEmpty()

                                           orderby c.RCount, c.Level
                                           select new IndexViewModel()
                                       {
                                           Chr = c.Name,
                                           GMember = ggg.G_Name
                                       };


            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
            {
                source = source.Where(p => p.Name.Contains(name));
            }

            var count = await source.CountAsync();
            var items = await source.Skip((page - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToListAsync();

            // формируем модель представления
            IndexViewModel model = new IndexViewModel
            {
                PageViewModel = new PageViewModel(count, page, pageSize),
                FilterViewModel = new FilterViewModel(db.Chr.ToList(), name),
                Chr = items
            };

            return View(model);
        }
```

В итоге я получаю 2 ошибки:

```
Не удается неявно преобразовать тип "string" в "System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Web.Models.DataBase.Chr>"

Не удается неявно преобразовать тип "string" в "System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Web.Models.GMember>"
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, что я сделал не правильно.

Comment: где вы их получаете то? В строчках каких?

Comment: Эти ошибки исправите сами, без посторонней помощи, надеюсь, бо компилятор покажет место. А вот вызов `db.Chr.ToList()` мне кажется гораздо более грубой ошибкой - это ж вы всю таблицу из БД на клиента тянете.

Comment: Добрый вечер. Ошибку студия показывает на строках Chr = c.Name,
                                           GMember = ggg.G_Name. Закомпилить само собой никак. И понять не могу в чём беда, а вторую табличку нужно подцепить...

Comment: В чём смысл делать джойн по Name, неужто нет Id? Тоже понимаю, что вам рыбу надо, но уж больно глаз цепляет...

Comment: К сожалению id нет в таблице.

Comment: ну а с чего вдруг это `IEnumerable<Chr> Chr` станет строкой?

Comment: `Подскажите пожалуйста, что я сделал не правильно.` - ошибки компилятора об этом говорят не двусмысленно и даже указывают конкретную строчку.